# Css semicirlce shape for footer

Tags: css, geometry

Hi I'm trying to make that shape using css:

[Semi cercle for footer section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W6ua.png)

(The circle its bigger than the screen, that's also a problem I think)

I have something similar using borders but it's not a perfect circle... Do you guys know any way to make it?

```css
#footer {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}

#inner_circle {
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  background-color: white;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 200px 200px;
}

#footer-stuff {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="inner_circle">
  <div>
  <div id="footer-stuff">
  <div>
<div>
```

Comment: Can we see your code so far so we can help you debug, through a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Sure, there it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [**radial-gradiant**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)

```css
div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(100% 200% at 50% 0, red 49%, black 51%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That does the trick, the problem I have now its that its not smooth

Comment: @CalistoQueets What you mean it's not smooth ?

Comment: This https://imgur.com/8UstWsR

Comment: @CalistoQueets You can see i lowered the first color stop ever so slightly to have a smooth curve this is a known issue with gradients, you'll have to lower the first AND/OR increase the second one enough to look good in your example

Comment: Thanks, I putted the second one to 50.05% and its pretty smooth, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.shape {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0rem 0rem 5rem 5rem / 0rem 0rem 4rem 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```